# Save Local Storage Javscript Check

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So I have a list of hotel data, and if you click on it the color of the box becomes red. The problem is, how to save the results of the box that has been clicked (turned red) in Local Storage.

[image]

```html
<script>
    let rooms = 0;
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
        console.log("Local Storage Available");
    else
        console.log("Opps.. No have Local Storage")
        
    function syncLocalStorage(activity, item, status) {
        switch (activity) {
            case 'ADD':
                break;
            case 'UPDATE':
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
        
    function spawnGate(gateName, roomCount) {
        const tpl = Array.from({
            length: roomCount
        }, (_, i) => i + 1).map(xx => {
            return `<div class="room" onclick="reserved(this, ${xx + rooms})"><span>${xx + rooms}</span></div>`;
        }).join('');
        rooms += roomCount;
        document.querySelector('#hotel').innerHTML += `<div class="gate">
            <h2>${gateName}</h2>
            <div class="rooms">${tpl}</div>
            </div>`;
        syncLocalStorage('ADD', tpl.value)
    }
        
    function reserved(el, num) {
        el.classList.toggle('reserved')
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        spawnGate('Gate A', 24);
        spawnGate('Gate B', 24);
        spawnGate('Gate C', 24);
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: does every box have a separate identity/uniquely identifiable  value?

Comment: Yes, every box has an identity

Comment: Then you can get the Respective Gate (like GateA, GateB etc) and also get the id of the box that has been clicked. Once you have something like this `Gate A { obj1, obj2}` etc. Store it in the local storage with `setItem` and once you get them with `getItem` just check if id is present then assign it the relevant style etc. Did you get it?

Try it and let me know I will put it up as answer as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

In your switch case you can call window.localStorage.getItem/ window.localStorage.setItem depending of your use case.

Check the docs out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Or you can use a library like [localforge](https://github.com/localForage/localForage)

Answer (score 0):

Each gate/room needs a ID that uniquely identifies it. Then you can use [`Window.localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save and retrieve data from the browser's local storage.

Example:

```js
function syncLocalStorage(activity, item, status) {
     // item being "Gate A" for instance with status "reserved"
     switch(activity) {
      case 'ADD':
        localStorage.setItem(item, status); 
        break;
      case 'UPDATE':
        // you could also use localStorage.getItem(item) first and update the item 
        // before updating it with setItem().
        localStorage.setItem(item, status); 
        break;
      case 'DELETE':
        localStorage.removeItem(item, status); 
        break;  
      default:
        // what should happen here?
        break;
      }
     }
}
```

When you load the page the next time, even in a new browser session, you can set the  gate values like so:

```js
document.getElementById("ID of Element").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

LocalStorage gets persisted across browser sessions, while [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is only valid during the current browser session.